# List length print 0 outside initstate but in initState it prints correct length in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching category list from another class into DetailCategory and try to filtered it, list viewed perfectly but unable to filterd it because it shows list length 0, I don't know why this is happening.

Here is my code:-

```
class DetailCategory extends StatefulWidget{
  List catList; bool isCat; String catId;
  DetailCategory(this.isCat, this.catList, this.catId);
  @override
  DetailCategoryState createState() => DetailCategoryState();
 }

 class DetailCategoryState extends State<DetailCategory>{
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List catList, filteredList; bool isCat; String catId;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    title: Text(Messages.appName),
   ),
   body: bodyWidget(),
  );
}

Widget bodyWidget(){
 Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 return Container(
   child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      Container(
        width: size.width*0.96,
        height: 50,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(width: 0.5), 
borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (value){
            filterdCategory(value);
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search in Category',
            border: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      Expanded(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          if(filteredList==null) Container()
          else GridView.count(
            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: filteredList.map((item) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.6)
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    child: Image.network(NetworkApi.categoryImagePath + item['image'], width: 90, 
height: 90, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                  Text(item['category_name'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: 
FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),)
                ],
              ),
            )).toList(),
           )
         ],
       ),))
     ],
   ),
  );
}

@override
void initState(){
  catList = widget.catList;
  filteredList = catList;
  isCat = widget.isCat;
  catId = widget.catId;
  print('list length: ${catList.length}');  // here list length is 6
  if(!isCat){
   fetchSubCategory();
  }
  super.initState();
 }



 fetchSubCategory(){
   // it will update later
 }

filterdCategory(String query){
 if(query.length > 2){
  this.filteredList.clear();
  print('${this.catList.length} ${query.length}'); //here it prints catList length 0 

  
  
   for(int i =0; i< this.catList.length; i++){
    if(this.catList[i]['category_name'].contains(query)){
      setState(() {
        this.filteredList.add(this.catList[i]);
      });
    }
  }

  if(this.filteredList.length == 0) {
    print('empty list');
    
    }
   }
  }
}
```

In initState it prints length 6 but in filterdCategory it prints length 0, I am new in Flutter and don't know what is happening here, Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: You are assigning catlist object to filredList and when you clear filteredlist it automatically clear the catlist too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `initState` with the below one and then try to filter the list.

```
@override
void initState(){
  catList = widget.catList;
  filteredList.addAll(catList);
  isCat = widget.isCat;
  catId = widget.catId;
  print('list length: ${catList.length}');  // here list length is 6
  if(!isCat){
   fetchSubCategory();
  }
  super.initState();
 }
```